# javascript autocomplete with source being names of files from a directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have spent a considerable amount of time googling this and was hoping someone on here had a reference or starting point I could expound upon.

I am looking for a javascript/jquery AutoComplete script which has the source being the file Names inside of a directory. I welcome any suggestions... thanks!

If worse comes to worse, I can just use an AutoComplete script (jqueryui or typahead.js) which has a source file for the results, but then I would have to code a separate function to automatically write to that file each time a new file is put into the directory or is deleted from it, and I am just trying to avoid that should something already exists.

**EDIT** server side scripting is unfortunately not an option for me. This is being run through an HTML Applications (HTA) file, so fortunately I do have additional freedoms than a typical web application.

Comment: You need to use a server side language to read the files in the directory and serve up their names as JSON. Do you have a server-side language available?

Comment: Hey Rob, 1) my employer is looking to avoid using/establishing a soft server for the application they have me working on. 2) if it helps, I am actually running this all through an HTA, so a lot of the typical restrictions with 'possible malicious web scripts' isn't an issue here if that helps you at all...

Answer (score 0):

I found an article for autocomplete textbox using jsp, jquery has been used but the code is written in such a way the data is retrieved from database and it comes as a suggestion when user types a letter or part of word.

if you are looking for it, you can click it [here](http://javainfinite.com/jsp-and-servlet/autocomplete-textbox-in-jsp-with-database/.)

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I am not able to us server side scripting to accomplish this.